# Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm when $n$ is not a power of 2

Tags: matrix

[image: Square-Matrix-Multiply-Recursive]

The above image, describing Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm, is from the book Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein.
The algorithm multiplies two square matrices of order $n$, where $n$ is a power of $2$, i.e., $n=2,4,8,16,32,\dots$ and so on.

> Can this algorithm be modified so that we can multiply two square matrices of order $n$, for all $n$?

Comment: I don't have my copy of CLR to hand, so I can't check: is this one of the exercises later in the chapter? If so, does that give any hints?

Comment: Pad the matrices with zeros.

Comment: In the first edition, this was exercise 31.2-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to pad the matrices with zeroes, using the block matrix identity
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
AB & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
.
$$

Here $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and the big matrices are $N\times N$ for some $N > n$. In other words, we add $N-n$ rows and $N-n$ columns of zeroes.

You can do this in two ways:

- Pad the original $n \times n$ matrices to $N \times N$ matrices, where $N$ is the closest power of 2. Note that $N < 2n$, so this doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity.
- Pad the matrices recursively. Whenever a recursive call gets $m \times m$ matrices with $m > 1$ odd, we pad them to $(m+1) \times (m+1)$ matrices by adding a single row and a single column of zeroes. This also doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity.

A third option is to make use of, say, a 3x3 matrix multiplication algorithm if the dimension is odd but divisible by 3. [Laderman](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1976-82-01/S0002-9904-1976-13988-2/S0002-9904-1976-13988-2.pdf) found such an algorithm which uses 23 multiplications (instead of the trivial 27).

Comment: this would alter the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Say  for n=27 and n=32 we would have same asymptotic complexity.

Comment: because we would actually be multiplying 32 X 32 matrix padded with zeros instead of 27 X 27 matrix. So can't the algorithm be modified keeping the complexity of the algorithm unaltered ?

Comment: @Sc00by_d00, it doesn't affect the complexity of the algorithm, assuming it's in $P$, because the padding is by a bounded factor.

Comment: The asymptotic complexity doesn’t depend on constant factors, which is all you lose here.

Comment: You don't use _many_ x3 steps. Here's what you do: For every n = 1, 2, 3, ... you find how to implement the product with the fewest number of operations. Choices are: 1. Naive algorithm. 2. Strassen with 0 or 1 padding rows / columns, calculating size n/2 in the optimal way. 3. Laderman's with 0, 1 or 2 padding rows / columns, calculating size n/3 in the optimal way. And you pick whatever is fastest. This is obviously never slower than Strassen. You should do that even just for Strassen. A 3x3 matrix will be faster with the naive implementation than by using Strassen (seven 2x2 matrices).

Comment: According to Wikipedia (if I understand it correctly) the product of 3x3 matrices can be done with 21 products, and 19 products is a proven lower bound so we could try to find ways to do it with 20 or 19 operations.